# How to solve dependency conflict with NPM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am trying to install all npm package I needed for the aws sample demo https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk-classroom-demo in my laptop. But always get the similar error when I want to run

```
npm install
```

I'm a bit curious if it's because I just got my  so I've got the wrong npm and node version

The error code shows that

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^8.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"*" from @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@2.34.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@"2.34.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!       dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.17.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (eslint-config-airbnb-typescript)
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@"2.34.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@2.34.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!       dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^2.17.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, eslint-config-airbnb-typescript)
npm ERR!     1 more (eslint-plugin-jest)
npm ERR!   7 more (babel-eslint, eslint-config-prettier, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.17.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.7.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@6.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@"^6.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (eslint-config-erb)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.34.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.17.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^2.7.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@6.3.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
npm ERR!       dev eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@"^6.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (eslint-config-erb)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/liycheng/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/liycheng/.npm/_logs/2022-06-18T00_11_27_159Z-debug-0.log
```

my node version and npm version are:

```
$ npm -v
8.9.0
$ node -v
v18.2.0
```

I tried to solve dependency conflict by

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above, you mentioned project repository consists `yarn.lock` file and doesn't consist `package-lock.json`. More than that inside the `package.json` there are many yarn commands defined. So the above project is initiated with `yarn`. So you need to use `yarn` commands instead of `npm`.

For that first check if you have `yarn` installed in your machine or not. using `yarn check`.
If not installed then install `yarn` using `npm install --global yarn`.
Then using `yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache` do a [clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69944063/6293914). It is a similar command to `npm ci` when you use `npm`.

To learn more about yarn check [yarn doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage)

Comment: Thank you Senthurkumaran, clean install solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The demo was built using yarn as a package manager - so I would suggest you use yarn instead of npm to build and run your application.

```bash
npm install --global yarn
yarn install
yarn start
```

If it works, the reason for you npm installation failing is most likely some additional information on dependencies stored in the yarn.lock file that is not evaluated when building with npm.

Comment: This is also a correct answer. But below I added a better answer.